# How to transfer business logic related state between Apache Helix instances?

Tags: apache-kafka, sharding, helix, rebalancing

Is Apache Helix capable of rebalancing data between nodes?
For examle I'm developing an in-memory database where some of the partitioned/sharded data needs to be moved to another node.
Is *messaging* or the *Application Property Store* a way to solve this problem or is it necessary to find another solution for data streaming between nodes?

Regarding the latter is it comfortable and efficient to use MessageQueues/Systems like RabbitMQ or Apache Kafka?

Comment: What type of in memory database? What kinds of data are in it?

Comment: @cricket_007 just arbitrary data. It could be any kind of state. The focus is on the transfer. I'm developing a service with state which gets partitioned and replicated. The in memory database was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I don't know Helix or Rabbit*

If you used Kafka, it would be persistent on servers rather than in memory, but you would need to write separate consumers to rebuild said database elsewhere.

For example, [Kafka Stream's KTable](https://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2018/04/05/of-stream-and-tables-in-kafka-and-stream-processing-part1/) object are exactly for that purpose. The partitioning of your topics would be up to you to implement if not using the default behaviour.